# Trouble plotting matlab matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, indices

I'm currently having some issues plotting a figure in matlab.

I currently have a data set imported from a DAQ software that took a sample size of 10,000 for both time and voltage. I attempted to non-dimensionalize the voltage and plot it using the following lines:

```
theta_1A = (d1Acoup - d1Acoup(10000,1))/(d1Acoup(1,1)-d1Acoup(10000,1));

figure
plot(t_1, theta_1A)
```

where theta_1A returns a column array of 10000x1--same as my time variable.
Unfortunately any time I try to plot theta_1A against time, I get the following error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What's the size of your time vector?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `plot`?

Comment: Right, my guess would be the same as TroyHaskin's: there must be a variable called `plot`. Look in your workspace or enter `whos plot` at the command line to check. If there is a variable called plot, MATLAB will not call the function `plot`, but will try to index into the variable using the variable `t_1` and `theta_1A` that are not positive integers or logicals. If you do not need the variable anymore, you can delete it with `clear plot`, otherwise copy it to a different name and clear it afterwards.

Comment: Yup you guys were right. Thank you!